# How does cereal mashing not produce off flavors due to above 170F boil temperatures?

Tags: mash

I have always read that over 170F grain mashes will get a very distinct off flavors.  How is it that during a cereal mash of grains (where you typically hold a mid-range temperature for a duration and then slowly increase to boil and hold) the process of exceeding the 170F temperature does not produce these off flavors?

I almost wonder if the gelatin substance after the mid-temperature duration holds in or prevents these off flavors from occurring entirely.

Comment: Where did you read that grain mashes above 170 F. will produce off flavours? It's a strange statement, as no one would ever mash at that temperature; the amylase enzymes in barley malt would be de-activated at such a high temperature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](http://byo.com/malt/item/147-arent-tannins-a-problem-when-you-boil-part-of-your-mash-during-a-decoction) to a similar question might be enlightening. In the case of a decoction mash, the tannins are not very soluble due to the low pH. It's really a combination of high temperatures and high pH that lead to extraction of tannins from the grain husks. The same would apply to a cereal mash.

The more important factor, though, is that you'd generally perform a cereal mash on grains that have no husk so there would be far less tannins present to begin with.